# Hide name of criterion in plot_tree() function

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I need the graph from plot_tree() function to be displayed without a criterion value in each node of tree. That is, I want to get a picture like that:

[image]

withoun using Paint :) How can I do it?

I also need to replace the word 'value' to the word 'proba', is it through changing code source only?

Comment: Did you try to use Tkinter? It's a nice python's module

Comment: just use the parameter `impurity=False` in the `plot_tree()` method. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `impurity=False` argument. Here is a reproducible piece of code for you -

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load data
iris = load_iris()

#model training
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

#plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
tree.plot_tree(clf, filled=True, impurity=False)  #<-----------
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought this argument made other function. I also need to replace the  word 'value' to the word 'proba', is it through changing code source only?

Comment: You can change the count to proportion by using `proportion=True` but the `values` label still stays the same. However, you can hide all the labels if that might work for you. Check [this documentation page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) to play around for more params